# Dates in Excel and Text

Tags: excel

Suppose I have a data set of the following form:

```
    Begin Date          End Date
    04/12/2005         06/12/2009
    07/10/2006         08/10/2010
        .                  .
        .                  .
```

Note that the actual dates begin on cells  `A2`  and  `B2` . I want to extract the year from these dates. When I write the following:

```
=right(b2,4)
```

I get something else like  `9976` . How does Excel convert dates into text and is there a way to preserve the date format when extracting the year?

Answer (score 4):

Use `=YEAR(B2)` to extract the year.

Excel dates are stored as integers, the number of days since 1/1/1900. If you change the displayed format of that cell to "General", you can see the date in its integer format.

So 6/12/2009 = 39976, and the rightmost four digits are 9976. But the `YEAR` function will just get the year for you.

If you want to convert the date into a text format, use the `TEXT` function with a date format. For example, if you want YYYY-MM format: `=TEXT(B2, "YYYY-MM")`.